# How to turn off read only mode when a workbook is opened?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro attached to a shared file which I scheduled to run every day. It doesn't save the workbook on completion.

I believe this is because the shared document opens in read only mode.

The macro searches cell values and if they meet the relevant conditions, the cell is highlighted red and the text inside the cell is replaced. The macro is set to save at the end.

```vb
Public Sub SendEmailReminder2()
    Dim lSecurity As Long

    lSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    
    'so the workbook doesn't open in protected view
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    
    Dim x As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("insert file path")
    
    Set c = Range("C2")
    'loop while cell is not empty
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        If c.Value <= Date - 45 Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
            c.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            c.Offset(0, -2).Interior.Color = vbRed
            c.Value = "Email Sent " & Date
            'build the message
            strbody = strbody & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, -2) & " - " & _
            c.Offset(0, -1) & " needs to be removed from New Releases"
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next cell
    Loop

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = strbody
        .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.AutomationSecurity = lSecurity
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the relevant parameters in the `.Open` method (*full list of parameters found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open)*)

```
Dim fn As String
fn = "insert file path"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn, _
                        ReadOnly:=False, _
                        IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Comment: this works for me when opening a book with 'Read Only' property activated. I can open, modify, and save the test book I made using this.